# java reading contents from a text file

Tags: java, file, split

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.*;

public class ReadFile {
public static void main(String[] args) {
int i=0;
String[] myStringArray = new String[]{ };
    try {
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         File file = new File("123.txt");

     input = new Scanner(file);
     while (input.hasNextLine()) {
         String line = input.nextLine();
         if(line.contains("int ")){
             System.out.println("found int "+(++i));
             System.out.println(line);
             myStringArray=line.split("[\\s,;]+");
             }
        }
System.out.println(myStringArray.length());
input.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
}
```

Why is it showing me error on `myStringArray.length()`
I wanted to read a text file which had contains as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{

int i=5;
int j=9;
int s,t;

s=i+3;
t=j+7;
q=j+4;

cout<<s<<t<<q;
}
```

I wanted to store all the variables value such as I wanted to store `i = 5`, `j = 9` and then my task was to print the expressions `s = i + 3` with the values of `i` and `j`.

Comment: length does not have parenthesis

Comment: Which is the error you're getting?

Comment: Sidenote: `import java.lang.*;` isn't needed. The JVM does that already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `myStringArray.length` and not `myStringArray.length()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
  myStringArray.length;
```

Instead of:

```
  myStringArray.length()
```